# How can I make a CMake Project that can be found with FIND_PACKAGE?

Tags: cmake

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/jc-lab/cmake-problem-1

```
CMakeLists.txt
main (Unmodifiable)
..CMakeLists.txt (Have a Find_Package(LibLZMA))
..main.cpp
lzma (Modifiable)
..CMakeLists.txt
..mylib.cpp
..include
....mylib.hpp
```

The 'main' directory cannot be modified here.

How can I fix it so I can use the LibLZMA library in the 'main' project?

I want to use LibLZMA as a subdirectory of root project in 'main' project with never install LibLZMA.

Comment: If you want to use standard [FindLibLZMA](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLibLZMA.html) script (shipped with CMake), you need to **install** LibLZMA. You may perform this installation locally (not system-wide). Also, you may install LibLZMA inside your `CMakeLists.txt` by issuing corresponded commands in [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/execute_process.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I want to build in Jenkins. Is there a way to not install it? If there is no way, consider execute_success.

Comment: "Is there a way to not install it?" - Yes, you may include LibLZMA via `add_subdirectory` and write `FindLibLZMA,cmake` script which will be used by `find_package(LibLZMA)` instead of the standard one. That script could set `LZMA_LIBRARIES` variable pointed to lzma **target**, so linking with that target  would build the library automatically.

Comment: Note, that you want answers with more specific suggestions (and more concrete code), you need to add **your code** to the **question post**. *Link* to the code (located on github) is **not sufficient**: the linked project could be deleted or modified, so the question would become unclear, and this would invalidate the answer.